# Leibniz rule for differentiation under the integral sign - example - don't we arrive at a slightly more complicated integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is an example of using the Leibniz rule for differentiation under the integral sign.

[Leibniz rule - general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

[image: pic001]

I wonder how does this calculation help in this case?

Starting from $I(y)$ we ended up with a slightly more complicated integral, didn't we?

[image: pic002]

So how can we continue from here?

Is this example just not good enough? I guess in general the idea is to be able to finish the calculations after using the Leibniz rule.

Where can I find a few more examples/problems of this kind to solve.
I just want to get some training after learning this Leibniz theorem/rule.

I am not sure the example above is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Leibniz rule is useful in several applications. For example, when calculating the derivative of a function after performing a integral transform like the Fourier or Laplace transform.

However, you should not hope that applying the rule simplifies an integral you want to calculate.

If you're looking for ressources to find examples, you can just google it. For example, I found  [this](https://learn.saylor.org/mod/book/view.php?id=37380&chapterid=21575) and [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf). Alternatively, just come up with a multivariate function of two variables, check for the conditions of the theorem, and then apply it. To check yourself, you can use computer algebra systems like Maple or Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Hm... So the idea of this example is just to show me one step, how to do that step. It doesn't necessarily lead to a full solution/calculation. Interesting...

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes, exactly. It's just an illustrative example.

Comment: Btw, I found these examples too, but they don't seem to be for the general case, where $a$ and $b$ (the integral bounds) are also functions.

Comment: @peter.petrov Okay, I see what you mean. But if you just want to practise the calculational part of the theorem, you can just put there any integral bounds you want.

Comment: :) Right but I was hoping that by using this Leibniz rule, I was going somewhere... and not just doing one mechanical step and stopping there. That was my point.

Comment: @peter.petrov In that case, maybe a more interesting application would be to prove the differentiation formulas for integral transforms.

Comment: OK, thanks. Btw, after arriving at that slightly more complicated integral, is it wrong to continue [this way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28x+*+exp%28y*x%29%29+dx+) and then just do $F(y^2+1) - F(y^2)$ , where $F$ is the primitive function (this indefinite integral). I was about to do that and then I stopped and I thought I am doing something wrong. Because if I am allowed to do that why not doing it from the very start (on that simpler integral) $I(y)$?

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes, that is also possible. In some cases, it may even be easier than applying the Leibniz rule. However, when faced with integrals that don't have a primitive such as $$y\mapsto\int e^{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2}dx,$$ the Leibniz rule is the only possibility.

Comment: Oh... so that is possible, it's not incorrect? I thought it is incorrect and that's why we have to use the Leibniz rule. Interesting, indeed.

Comment: I thought it's incorrect to do that because $y$ is both under the integral sign and also in the bounds of the integral. So it seemed incorrect to me to proceed that way. Are you sure this approach which I suggested is OK? If so, why is it correct? I guess because I can put $z$ instead of $y$ in the bounds of the integral, then do what I do, then set $z=y$ at the very end. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I calculated it both ways (with Leibniz rule and without), and got the same result. Very interesting. Thank you.